# ARCore how to change "fit to scan image you're scanning" text?

Tags: java, android, arcore

I am fairly new to ARCore and hope that my question is not too obvious, but I would like to know how to change the instruction text on the imageview which by default says "Fit the image you're scanning"? I tried to change the text attribute to android:text="Hello" but it does not change anything.

That's what it currently looks like:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view_fit_to_scan"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="@string/fit_image_to_scan"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/fit_to_scan"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Thank you in advance

Alex